# On $GL_2(\mathbb F_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider $G:=GL_2(\mathbb F_3)$. I have to extrapolate as much information about it as I can. Without computations.

First of all: I think someone else has already done this before me, hence if you know where to find some good pdf, please give me the link!

Then:

$|G|=(3^2-1)(3^2-3)=48=3\cdot2^{4}$

We know that $N:=SL_2(\mathbb F_3)\unlhd G$; in fact $N=\ker(\det)$, where $\det:G\rightarrow \mathbb F_3^{\times}$. Being $\det$ surjective, we have that $G/N\simeq\mathbb F_3^{\times}$, from which $|N|=24$.

Then I'm searching for elements of $N$ of order $2$: i.e. $g\in N$ s.t. $g^2=1$. So let's look at the minimal polynomial of such an element, call it $f$. It will divide $X^2-1$, so $f$ must be $X-1,\;X+1$ or $X^2-1$.

If $f(X)=X-1$ then $g=1$ so it wouldn't have order $2$. Hence $f(X)\neq X-1$.

My teacher wrote that $f(X)=X+1$ because if $f(X)=X^2-1$ then $\det(g)=-1$, from which we have a contradiction because $g\notin N$. But I can't understand why!

I thought that $G$ is a subset of the ring $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb F_3)$, which is not a integer domain, hence I can't argue as follows: $g-1\neq0,\;g^2-1=0\Rightarrow g+1=0$. But no more.

Can someone help me to understand why $f(X)=X^2-1\;\Longrightarrow\det(g)=-1$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You wrot «I have to extrapolate as much information about it as I can», but did not really tell us what you mean.

Comment: You can't look at $G$ as a ring: that does not make any sense. You *could* view it as a subset of the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb F_3$, but that is quite a different thing!

Comment: Use the formula $ad-bc$ for the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix and note that the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is the determinant which is discussed in great detail here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89069/should-the-formula-for-the-inverse-of-a-2x2-matrix-be-obvious/89080#89080

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez:«I have to extrapolate as much information about it as I can» was the incipit of the exercise. I only rewrote it. But my problem is the last line I wrote, the fact about the minimal polynomial. The question of ring: you're right, I'm tired. I'm gonna edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its minimal polynomial of an element in $SL_2(F_3)$ is $X^2-1$, then that polynomial is also its characteristic polynomial and its independent term is its determinant: this is absurd, as the element is in $SL_2(F_3)$.